# Como puedo solucionar el error invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'registro*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c

Al compilar mi codigo me marca el error "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'registro*' [-fpermissive]"

La aplicación debe ser capaz de mantener información de:

Titulo del Libro
Autores
Editorial
Año de edición

Asimismo, la aplicación tendrá el siguiente menu:

Menu Biblioteca

1. Agregar nuevo libro
2. Listar libros biblioteca
3. Buscar Libro
4. Eliminar Libro
5. Salir.
   Seleccione una opción:

Al seleccionar la opción 1, se solicitará se ingrese los datos del libro como son: el titulo del libro, los autores, la editorial y el año de edición.
Al seleccionar la opción 2, se listarán todos los libros que se encuentran en la biblioteca.
Al seleccionar la opción 3, se solicitará que se ingrese parte del nombre del libro y se mostrarán los títulos de todos los libros que coincidan con la búsqueda.
Al seleccionar la opción 4, se solicitará se ingrese el índice del libro a eliminar.
Al seleccionar la opción 9, se terminará el programa.

Por lo que para su implementación se requiere una estructura de datos con el nombre libro con los siguientes campos:
Titulo
Autores
Editorial
Año de edición.

Se requerirá la estructura de lista doblemente enlazada con el nombre Nodo que estará formada por las siguientes variables:
libro de tipo apuntador a una estructura de tipo Libro.
Next de tipo apuntador a una estructura de tipo Nodo.
Prev de tipo apuntador a una estructura de tipo Nodo.

Aqui dejo mi codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct registro{
    char tit[80];
    char aut[80];
    char edi[80];
    char ano[4];
};
struct registro *registros = NULL;
int tot = 0;

void nuevo();
void buscar();

int main(){
    int opc;
    Inicio:
    system("cls");
    system("color 0B");
    printf("\n\n\n\tMenu Biblioteca\n");
    printf("\n1. Agregar nuevo libro");
    printf("\n2. Listar libros");
    printf("\n3. Buscar libro");
    printf("\n4. Eliminar libro");
    printf("\n9. Salir");
    printf("\n\nSeleccione una opcion:\t");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    printf("\n");
    switch (opc){
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            nuevo();
        break;
        case 2: 
            system("cls");
        break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
        break;
        case 4: 
            system("cls");
        break;
        case 9:
            system("pause");
        break;
        default:
            printf("Opcion invalida");
            printf("\nPor favor seleccione una opcion valida");
            goto Inicio;
        break;
    }
}

void nuevo(){
    registros = realloc(registros,sizeof(struct registro)*(tot+1));
    printf("\nIngrese el nombre del libro %i", tot+1);
    fgets(registros[tot].tit,80,stdin);
    printf("\nIngrese el autor%ces%c del libro %i",40,41, tot+1);
    fgets(registros[tot].aut,80,stdin);
    printf("\nIngrese la editorial del libro %i", tot+1);
    fgets(registros[tot].edi,80,stdin);
    printf("\nIngrese el a%co del libro %i",164, tot+1);
    fgets(registros[tot].ano,4,stdin);
    tot++;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sucede porque estas escribiendo C, y luego compilando con C++, que es mas restrictivo. La solución tendría que ser simple, añade un cast. Tendria que ser: `registros = (struct registro*) realloc(...);`

Answer (score 1):

Estas compilando usando Dev-C++. De fondo, como indica el, nombre usa un compilador de C++ (g++ para ser especifico).

Según la [documentacion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), `realloc` retorna un `void*`. Tu luego lo asignas a un `struct registro*`, haciendo una conversión implícita de `void*` a `struct registro*`. Esto según el estándar de C esta perfectamente bien, pero como estas usando un compilador de C++, tenemos que ver que dice C++ sobre esto.

Yo utilice [esta copia del estandar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

> 4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]
>
> 1. A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
>    zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the
>    result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or
>    function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a null pointer conversion. Two null pointer values of the
>    same type shall compare equal. The conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is
>    a single conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4).
>    A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. [ Note: The
>    resulting prvalue is not a null pointer value. — end note ]
> 2. A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T,” where T is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
>    to cv void”. The result of converting a “pointer to cv T” to a “pointer to cv void” points to the start of
>    the storage location where the object of type T resides, as if the object is a most derived object (1.8) of type
>    T (that is, not a base class subobject). The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the
>    destination type.
> 3. A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
>    to cv B”, where B is a base class (Clause 10) of D. If B is an inaccessible (Clause 11) or ambiguous (10.2)
>    base class of D, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion is a
>    pointer to the base class subobject of the derived class object. The null pointer value is converted to the
>    null pointer value of the destination type

Es un poco complicado de leer, pero en resumen, puedes hacer conversiones implícitas entre tipos de punteros si se cumple una de las siguientes condiciones<sup>1</sup>:

1. Estas convirtiendo una constante nula a cualquier tipo de puntero.

```cpp
int* a = nullptr;
double* b = NULL;
float* c = 0;
```

2. Un puntero de cualquier tipo, a un puntero de tipo `void`.

```cpp
int a = 1;
void* ptr = &a;
```

3. Un puntero de una clase derivada, a un puntero de su clase padre.

```cpp
class A {};
class B : public A {};

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/[]) {
    B b;
    A* ptr = &b;
    return 0;
}
```

La conversión que estas tratando de hacer no encaja en ninguna de estas, así que no la puedes hacer de forma implícita. La solución es sencilla, se explicito con la conversión.

Si quieres mantener el código estilo C, haz:

```cpp
registros = (struct registro*)realloc(registros,sizeof(struct registro)*(tot+1));
```

O si quieres hacerlo como se debería en C++ aprovechando que estas compilando con el mismo:

```cpp
registros = static_cast<struct registro*>(realloc(registros,sizeof(struct registro)*(tot+1)));
```

Lo optimo siempre seria que usaras un compilador de C, así no tendrías que usar trucos para acomodarte al compilador de C++.

---

---

**1:** De forma simplificada claramente, si quieres la explicación completa has el esfuerzo de entender el estándar. Si por las simplificaciones hago un comentario incorrecto, por favor indíquenmelo en los comentarios